# How to add member NOT peer node to private ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, poa

I followed this [parity-poa](https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial) tutorial to build a private POA ethereum network in local. I want to add member node to this network . so i run parity client with below configuration

toml file:

```
[parity]
base_path = "3"

[network]
id = 8995
port = 30303
# Override the bootnodes from selected chain file.
bootnodes = ["enode://XXX@localhost:30300", "enode://XXXX@localhost:30301"
]
# Enable or disable new peers discovery.
discovery = false

[rpc]
port = 8543
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8453
[ipc]
disable = true
```

I haven't passed `chain = "genesis.json"` in above file because i want it to work just like public ethereum network i.e when we start parity/geth the blocks get automatically download in local system.

From few links i learn that adding `bootnodes` will help to achieve this task .. but it does not work . the parity client is asking for genesis file.

So How can i add member node to this network in my local system without genesis file.

Answer (score 0):

The miners/ validators will be in the genesis file. You have to start peers with the same genesis file and set discovery to true.

Once you do this, any client running that genesis file and toml configuration can join the network